# how to send mulitple image upload form data via ajax to node.js

Tags: ajax, image, node.js

i want to send form data to server side via jQueryajax . i am uploading multiple images .

when i press submit button, i should send images path via ajax to server(node.js)

but here i am using form so

how to do that ?
i have tried this one.but it is not working for multiple image upload

http://blog.w3villa.com/websites/uploading-filesimage-with-ajax-jquery-without-submitting-a-form/

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

thing which you need to take care is cross-browser compatibility and unfortunately Formdata in not supported in Internet Explorer.

I would suggest you to use Uploadify JQuery plugin. You can download it from http://www.uploadify.com/. You can use the flash version, I have tested it and it works fine with IE as well.

Best of Luck.